# Python "Error 'dict' object has no attribute 'load'"

Tags: python, json, urllib2

I am sort of new to Python and I've looked around for this, but basically what I'm making is an IRC bot. Now, the thing that's giving me an issue is a YouTube extract command I added.
Here is the source:

```
if text.find(':'+prefix+'yt') != -1:
    idb = text.split(':'+prefix+'yt')
    videoid = idb[1].strip()
    if len(videoid) == 11:
        try:
            url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+videoid+'?alt=json&v=2'
            json = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
            title = json['entry']['title']['$t']
            author = json['entry']['author'][0]['name']['$t']
            irc.send('PRIVMSG '+home+' :'+str(title)+' | by '+str(author)+' | http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+str(videoid)+' \r\n')
        except Exception, e:
            irc.send('PRIVMSG '+home+' :Could not look up video, check your ID. \r\n')
            print "Error",e
            pass
    else:
        irc.send('PRIVMSG '+home+' :Could not look up video, video ID must be at least 11 characters. \r\n');
```

What happens is, the first try it works properly:

```
[14:57:23] <@Snowstormer> @yt Kwwl9jiJ1A4
[14:57:24] <GotBot> "Take Back the Night" - A Minecraft Original Music Video | by CaptainSparklez | http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kwwl9jiJ1A4
```

However the next time it's:

```
[14:57:27] <@Snowstormer> @yt Kwwl9jiJ1A4
[14:57:27] <GotBot> Could not look up video, check your ID.
```

Which is only meant to show up if the ID is the proper length but a video with it doesn't exist.

Before I added the Exception, the bot just straight up disconnected. In the CMD line it shows:

```
Error 'dict' object has no attribute 'load'
```

I tried Googling without a result. I am running Windows so no Unix-trickery will apply (if there is any, but I figured I should put it out there).

I realize this might be bit of a localized question, but I do need help nevertheless.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are storing the result of `json.load` in a variable named `json`, effectively overriding the module `json`. This is most likely not what you want to achieve. Try renaming that.

Comment: I ended up with the same issue, reason I named my var json was that I had seen it in an example elsewhere.  No issue until I ended needing to use the json library after I created my var.  Need to update those examples.